# SQL Server 2008 trigger update when specific column changes

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

Other solutions got me this far, but ultimately things are not working for me.

I have a column in `tbl_activity` named `abstract`. When `tbl_activity.abstract` changes, I want to set `tbl_activity.flag = 0`.

My 2 versions of the trigger will set flag = 0, but then I cannot set flag back to 1, because changing that flag causes it to trigger, and it keeps setting the flag = 0. I've tried comparing old to new values, deleted to inserted values, and tried `INSTEAD OF INSERT`.

Can someone please examine this code and tell me what I'm missing?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AbstractChange] --trigger name
ON [dbo].[cpy_activity] --table using the trigger
INSTEAD OF UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
     UPDATE a 
     SET a.flag = 0
     FROM tbl_activity a 
     INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON a.activityid = i.activityid
     INNER JOIN DELETED d ON d.activityid = i.activityid
     WHERE d.abstract NOT LIKE i.abstract
```

This results in "Command[s] completed successfully" - but when a column other than `abstract` changes, the trigger always sets `flag = 0`. Ideas?

Comment: What **datatype** is that `abstract` column???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the **datatype** of `abstract` is - but I'm kinda guessing that the cause of your troubles is using the `NOT LIKE` operator in your trigger - try this instead:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AbstractChange] --trigger name
ON [dbo].[cpy_activity] --table using the trigger
INSTEAD OF UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
     UPDATE a 
     SET a.flag = 0
     FROM tbl_activity a 
     INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON a.activityid = i.activityid
     INNER JOIN DELETED d ON d.activityid = i.activityid
     WHERE d.abstract <> i.abstract   -- use the usual *not equal* operator <> here
```

Does that change anything?

Also: **why** is the trigger on `cpy_activity`, but inside the trigger, you're using `tbl_activity` - seems a bit odd, really .....

Comment: thx, marc - typo on my part [from cleaning the code away from work context] - i should keep them all 'tbl_activity'. ALSO: misdirection on my part, the "INSTEAD OF" simply performs the SET a.flag=0, instead of doing what it is supposed to do. SO - i abandoned INSTEAD OF, and the only way i can find to get it to work is regrettably to change the var type of abstract [info field, text only, including html tags, etc].

Comment: hi, Marc btw that was helpful, thank you. looking back on it i wanted to further elucidate a couple of things: the original error of the trigger "not changing" the target field was because elsewhere when the target field was directly changed to 1, it tripped the trigger to then react and reset it back to 0. so i added a clause "AND (d.targetfield = i.targetfield and d.targetfield = 1)", thereby checking if the field going into the trigger that it was not changed externally, and additionally that only when it starts as a 1, then and only then reset it to 0.

Comment: additionally, the original hard error i was getting was, "Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables.” the original tbl_activity.abstract field was text. we are using varchar(max) now, seeing how text, ntext, and images column names are deprecated anyway. again thx for your help!!

Comment: hey, my apologies, Marc for not checking the answer sooner! i definitely do want to recognize you and others for helping. great awesome site this stackoverflow!!

Answer (score 0):

since the code i posted to ask my question, contained the erroneous use of INSTEAD OF - my "answer" at this point is that i changed my tbl_activity.abstract field from type Text to type Varchar(MAX) not null. One of the original problems was that the SQL trigger would not allow use of a text field. I will post that question properly on another post. Meanwhile, this code works, in the context where the "abstract" field is type varchar:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AbstractChange] --trigger name
ON  [dbo].[tbl_activity] --table using the trigger
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS UPDATE a 
set a.flag = 0 --target action when above table is changed
FROM tbl_activity a 
 INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON a.activityid = i.activityid
 INNER JOIN DELETED d ON d.activityid = i.activityid
WHERE d.abstract <> i.abstract
```